# ReactJS - axios request at componentDidUpdate()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've learned that, in Reactjs:

> `componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

I have this method in my component that sends a network request with axio:

```
getFeatures(event) {
    const data = {
      spotify_token: this.props.spotifyToken
    };
    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/features/${this.props.userId}/${this.props.spotifyToken}`;
    axios.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      });
  };
```

The `getFeatures()` method is called after props are obtained, like so:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  this.getFeatures();
}
```

---

The call ends up working however, before it works it throws a 404 error and a malformed `POST` request, while both required props have not yet been updated to their values:

1. `POST http://localhost/features//undefined 404 (NOT FOUND)`
2. `XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/features/1/undefined"`

---

How do I fix these errors before it works?

Comment: Is the `spotifyToken` prop ever being supplied to your component? This may be due to the `spotifyToken` prop being optional (perhaps supplied at a later time?)

Comment: sure, it is being supplied, after a click on a button. I've ommited that for brevity. it ends up working, with token being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a component life-cycle/state issue, where `prop`'s that are required for your component to function correctly are not guaranteed to be present or defined throughout your components life span.

A simple solution would be to apply [defensive programming principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) to your `getFeatures()` method:

```
getFeatures(spotifyToken, userId) {

  /* If required props are not defined, early exit as the request
     cannot be completed */
  if (!spotifyToken || !userId) {
    return;
  }

  /* The required props are present so attempt network request */
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
    Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
  }

  const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/features/${userId}/${spotifyToken}`;
  axios.post(url, data, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { spotify_token, userId } = this.props;

    if(prevProps.spotify_token !== spotify_token || prevProps.userId !== userId) {
        /* If a change occurred in token or user id, attempt to get 
        features */
        this.getFeatures(spotify_token, userId);
    }
}
```

These changes mean that once all required `prop` data is present, your network request will be performed.

If for instance, both the `spotify_token` and `userId` props are supplied at a later time (ie after a user interaction like a button click), then the `componentDidUpdate()` method will be called and the network request will be attempted.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @8-BitBorges you're welcome! The performance overhead here is very minimal. Glad I could help you :-)

Comment: IMO I think the conditional logic should be in `componentDidUpdate` so that `getFeatures` never gets called if not necessary.  Following the Single Responsibility Principle, `getFeatures` should be responsible for...getting features, not decididng if the features should be fetched.

Comment: @larz yes agreed

Comment: Also, just upgrade to a version of React with hooks :) That simplifies all of this

Comment: @larz agreed! Had to stop for a moment and get into the "class" mindset with this answer :)

Comment: @DacreDenny me too! Which is funny, since it's been less than a year since they were initially released ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Dacre Deny what is strange here is that this solution triggers axios call twice....

Comment: That's likely because your props are being changed multiple times, which it turn causes the `getFeatures()` method to be called multiple times. To avoid this, you may want to consider comparing new props with previous props, to determin if `getFeatures()` should be called as shown here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `spotifyToken` and `userId` props are not ready when the component is updated and `getFeatures` is called. Check if they're defined.

Also, calling the API on **every update** of the UI is not a good idea. Do some validity check like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { spotifyToken, userId } = this.props;
  if (spotifyToken && userId && (spotifyToken !== prevProps.spotifyToken || userId !== prevProps.userId)) {
    this.getFeatures();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the cause, seeing that the `userId` prop is defined where as the  `spotifyToken` is not.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but since it eventually succeeds, it probably isn't an issue of scope/the function not having the correct `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to add some conditionals to your `componentDidUpdate` to ensure that `getFeatures` isn't called every single time a prop or state changes.  After initial mount, every single change will trigger this, which is probably why you are getting the weird errors with `undefined` in the URL.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  const { spotifyToken, userId } = prevProps;

  if (spotifyToken && userId && (spotifyToken !== this.props.spotifyToken || userId !== this.props.userId)) {
    this.getFeatures();
  }
}
```

Since it eventually succeeds, that makes me think that either `spotifyToken` or `userId` are being updated after your component has initially mounted, but one or the other is `undefined`, an empty string, or something else incorrect.

FWIW, using the latest version of `React` with hooks helps tidy this up immensely.  You can just add your dependencies after `useEffect` and that takes care of the messy logic of that conditional.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (spotifyToken && userId) getFeatures();
}, [spotifyToken, userId]);
```

Comment: you are right on your comment below. on a second thought, I think the canonical way is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs, you should compare current props to previous props before causing side effects like API calls or state updates.

Could you update the `componentDidUpdate` to something like this and try again -

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.spotifyToken !== prevProps.spotifyToken) {
    this.getFeatures(this.props.spotifyToken)
  }
}
```

> Additionally you should add a validation for `this.props.spotifyToken` for empty or undefined and not make the API call.

Comment: Well, this answer gives you insight into what could be done. The dev should handle undefined userId same as the token. Couldn't expect an exact answer.